# Silverlight - How to do internationalization in XAML?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, xaml, internationalization

can anybody give me a link or explain me how to do internationalization in silverlight? I tried for 1 hour and any site seems to be working. I want use resource files inside a usercontrol. But once I saw that I dont need to register the resource file on every user control.

If exists a best model, please show me :U.
I don't want to simple assign resource values by code behind. That I know how to do.

I want to do in XAML!

Answer (score 0):

You want to use Data Binding. Make your RESX resource available to XAML. Here's more info:

http://gargmanoj.wordpress.com/2009/03/18/accessing-strings-from-resource-file-in-xaml-markup/